# If a polynomial maps a region onto a neighborhood of zero, does it follow that it has a zero in some "robust" sense?

Tags: calculus, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $B^n\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ be a unit ball, $P: B^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is polynomial in each component, and assume that the image of $P$ contains $0$ in its interior. Does it follow that for some $\epsilon$, each continuous $g: B^n\to\Bbb R^m$ with $\|g-P\|_\infty\leq\epsilon$ has a root?

For non-polynomial continuous functions $P$, the answer is clearly no. For example, $P: B^2\to\Bbb R^2$ defined in polar coordinates by $P(r,\phi)=(r,4\cos \phi)$, maps $B^2$ onto $B^2$ and each circle of radius $r$ is mapped surjectively to itself with degree $0$ (the "$4>\pi$" is needed to ensure that it goes over all the circle, there and back). There are arbitrary close continuous perturbations of $P$ with no root, because one can only change $P$ inside an arbitrary small ball $B(\epsilon)$ and avoid zero inside.

The question is: can something like that happen, if we require $P$ to be a polynomial?

Comment: Does that norm mean the max value on the ball $B^n$?

Comment: Gregory, yes, thank you. I mean the max-norm.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my last comment, the rub is that the image of $P$ contains a zero *in its interior*.  That seems plausible.

Comment: (Yes, I mean that for counter-examples, we need to have dimensions at least 2, even in the non-polynomial setting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a counterexample would be
$$ P(x,y) = (x^2-\tfrac14, xy^2) $$

Because it has two zeroes in the unit ball at $(\pm\frac12,0)$ the image of the *entire* unit ball can have $(0,0)$ as an interior point even though this is not true for smaller balls centered at each of the zeroes.

However,
$$ g_\varepsilon(x,y) = (x^2-\tfrac14, xy^2+x\varepsilon) $$
does not have any zeroes for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still interested whather this can happen if $x$ is a root and arbitrary small neighborhood of $x$ is mapped to a neighborhood of $0$ (which happens in case of the non-polynomial $P$ in the question).. But you answered my question as it stands, of course.